# Dimensional Reduction on multi dependent variable for propensity score matching

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, propensity-scores

I have an analysis project and I am not quite sure about my analysis plan.
The data context are about the treatment effect with confounding variables is well-established. But it have many dependent variable and I find hard to do.

Theses are requirements to perform

1. I must do propensity score matching.
2. Some variables are repeated measurement.
3. Calculate Treatment effect size by t-test to find the difference.

The muti-variate dependent variable are tricky to perform propensity score matching. So I come with analysis plan.

1. Dimension reduced all dependent variable to 1 factor.
2. Estimate factor score and define 50 percentile of factor score above as 1 and 0 to vice vesa.
3. Use the define dependent factor score to perform propension score matching.
4. Calculate treatment effect size by t-test for each dependent variable on original data.

Do this all step all right to do? if not. I love to see other technique or suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Propensity score matching is not a good idea, and propensity scores in general are used far too often.  See https://hbiostat.org/bbr/propensity

Comment: I think so. if it were me I would do SEM in this case.

Comment: Why not do each dependent varaible separately?

Comment: Do you really mean dependent variable, or do you mean treatment? You don't need the dependent variable to do propensity score matching. It sounds like you have a continuous treatment measured with error by multiple indicators, not multiple outcomes. Is that accurate?